# How to get Mongo documents and return them as a JSON API response

Tags: json, mongodb, go

I'm writing an API which retrieves Mongo documents and return those documents as a JSON response.

I can certainly do this by creating a struct with the proper field mappings, but since i'm not processing these documents, I simply want to convert the raw data I get from the code below to JSON. My API will then return the JSON as a response.

I have the following code:

```
var raw []bson.Raw
err = myCollection.Find(
      bson.M{"name": name},
).All(&raw)
```

I want to convert raw to JSON.  How would I do that?  Is there a better of this this other than by starting to create a bson.Raw?

```
Tech stack:
Go 1.1
mgo v1  http://godoc.org/labix.org/v1/mgo
bson v1 http://godoc.org/labix.org/v1/mgo/bson
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since you want json. Have you looked at the "encoding/json" package that comes with go? How far did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmarshal it into maps instead:

```
var maps []bson.M
err = myCollection.Find(bson.M{"name": name}).All(&maps)
```

This way you can provide these same maps to the `encoding/json` package's `Marshal` function.